# Reusing code from a method which performs a flag check

Tags: python, refactoring

I have a method which calls a few other methods based on a flag..

```
def methodA(self):
    if doc['flag']:
         self.method1()      
         self.method2()
```

Now, i have to make a call to the methodA() from another place which needs to do essentially the same things, but independent of doc['flag'] (call self.method1() and self.method2() regardless of whether flag is true or false) Is there a nice way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not call `method1()` and `method2()` directly?

Comment: Sorry, I might have not been clear..I have about 20 lines within methodA() which are making the same calls that I need, but with the flag check, so I'd prefer to reuse methodA()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do it is:

```
def methodA(self):
    if doc['flag']:
        self.anotherMethod()

def anotherMethod(self):
    self.method1()      
    self.method2()
```

Or:

```
def methodB(self, flag=False, execute_anyways=False):
    if not flag and not execute_anyways:
        return #Note that while calling, you would be sending True, or False. If flag=None, it would execute. 
    self.method1()      
    self.method2()

def methodA(self):
    self.methodB(flag=doc['flag'])
```

And in the other instance, just call

```
self.methodB(execute_anyways=True) #Now, the flag would have the default value of None, and would execute.
```

Comment: Surely you can avoid the commented trap by using `if flag: self.method1(); self.method2()`.  Then the existing code calling `MethodA()` would continue to work as before; the new code would need to add `True` as an argument so that it calls `method1()` and `method2()` unconditionally.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. I just tweaked the logic a bit to make it more explicit. I trust this should work better, and more explicitly